# How can I get nested case Arguments to return values

Tags: sql-server

I want 2 values out of this nest of case argument's so I can insert them into a results table to check for matches, I then update the results from the `#game` table. I have put update as part of the select statement.
I get

> invalid column error

on the `standard_matches` and `bonus_match`.
I then try and get a value after the case argument and  with the same error.
This is the case argument code.

```
BEGIN   -- 
    -- update #game set gwn = standard_matches ,gsn = bonus_match from 
-- where gameno = 1 
    --  from
        SELECT
            @Ball1 AS Ball1,
            @Ball2 AS Ball2,
            @Ball3 AS Ball3,
            @Ball4 AS Ball4,
            @Ball5 AS Ball5,
            @Ball6 AS Ball6,
            standard_matches
            bonus_match
        from #draws
    CROSS APPLY 
        ( SELECT
            CASE WHEN Winningball1 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 end + 
            CASE WHEN Winningball2 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 ENd +
            CASE WHEN Winningball3 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END +
            CASE WHEN Winningball4 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END +
            CASE WHEN Winningball5 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END +
            CASE WHEN Winningball6 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END as standard_matches,
            CASE WHEN Bonusball1 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END +
            CASE WHEN Bonusball2 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END as bonus_match
        ) AS ca1 
        set @sm = standard_matches
        set @bm = bonus_match
        update #game set gwn = @sm ,gsn = @bm where gno = 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want ?

```
; WITH ca1 AS
(
    SELECT
            standard_matches,  -- missing comma
            bonus_match
        from #draws
    CROSS APPLY 
        ( 
      SELECT
            CASE WHEN Winningball1 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 end + 
            CASE WHEN Winningball2 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 ENd +
            CASE WHEN Winningball3 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END +
            CASE WHEN Winningball4 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END +
            CASE WHEN Winningball5 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END +
            CASE WHEN Winningball6 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END as standard_matches,
            CASE WHEN Bonusball1 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END +
            CASE WHEN Bonusball2 IN (@Ball1, @Ball2, @Ball3, @Ball4, @Ball5, @Ball6) THEN 1 END as bonus_match
        ) a
)
UPDATE  g
SET gwn = ca1.standard_matches,
    gsn = ca1.bonus_match
FROM    #game g
CROSS JOIN ca1
WHERE   g.gno = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I still get the error invalid column name for standard_matches and bonus_match in the select and update statements. the case argument can see the column as int

Comment: can you post your latest query ?

Comment: Hi Squirrel the column names are not the same this is the code

Comment: My 3 year old deleted my code when she gave me a hug. I just re typed it and it is working thanks